# Временный вход на сайт

Tags: django

Добрый день. На некоторых сайтах на форме входа есть пункт "запомнить меня". Если его отключить, то вход будет осуществлён пока пользователь не закрыл браузер. Подскажите, как такое проще всего реализовать в django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Сессии Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions)

Comment: спасибо, set_expiry() как то не заметил.